# VS2005 and Windows SDK 7.1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, platform-sdk

Running the WindowsSdkVer.exe shipped with Platform SDK 7.1 does not work.
None of the .BAT files in VS 2005 get updated.

can anyone please tell me how to correct this?
Also, how do I verify that VS2005 is using Platform SDK 7.1?

There are several articles for this in MSDN but none of them for above configuration.
Also, none of them describe the concrete way / definate way of verifying this

Comment: VS2005 never used the SDK, it shipped with a private copy of the SDK files.  If 7.1 is important then do consider updating VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to manually set the include and lib paths of the VS environment under

> Tools->Options->VC++ Directories

or something like that (it's been a while).

For verification, you can add the `/showIncludes` parameter to the additional compiler options of the project, and `/verbose:lib` to the additional linker options to double check that the correct headers/libraries are being used when compiling/linking the project.

IIRC there was some kind of incompatibility between one of the newer versions of the SDK (could have been version 7) and using VS2005, but I can't recall off hand what that was.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method for using Windows SDK 7.1 with Visual Studio 2005.

[Configuring Visual Studio for Visual C++ Development with the Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764(v=vs.100).aspx)

In the link , you can find the contents with 
"To use the Windows SDK Configuration Tool in Visual Studio 2008".

Even though it has such title, you can use the same procedure also for VS2005.

1. Start the Windows SDK Configuration Tool by clicking Start, then All Programs, then Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1, and then **Visual Studio Registration**.
2. Right-click **Windows SDK Configuration Tool** and then click Run as 
   administrator.
3. In the Windows SDK Configuration Tool, in the list, select **v7.1**.
4. Click **Make Current**.